# Distutils: Compiling an Objective-C++ source file as part of a C++ extension

Tags: python, setuptools, objective-c++, distutils, python-c-api

I am writing a Python extension in C++. I compile it by defining a list of the constituent source files in my `setup.py` file, like so:

```py
extensions = {
    'im': [
        "im/src/buffer.cpp",
        "im/src/detail.cpp",
        "im/src/gil.cpp",
        "im/src/halideimage.cpp",
        "im/src/hybrid.cpp",
        "im/src/hybridimage.cpp",
        "im/src/options.cpp",
        "im/src/pybuffer.cpp",
        "im/src/pycapsule.cpp",
        "im/src/structcode.cpp",
        "im/src/typecode.cpp",
        "im/src/module.cpp"
    ],
}
```

… these are used to define an instance of `setuptools.Extension` which is ultimately passed to the `setup()` function. This has all worked just fine throughout the project, until now, when I tried to add a platform-specific bit:

```py
preview_source = (sys.platform == 'darwin') and 'im/src/plat/preview_mac.mm' or \
                  (sys.platform == 'linux') and 'im/src/plat/preview_linux.cpp' or \
                  (sys.platform == 'win32') and 'im/src/plat/preview_windows.cpp' or \
                                                'im/src/plat/preview.cpp'

extensions = {
    'im': [
        "im/src/buffer.cpp",
        "im/src/detail.cpp",
        "im/src/gil.cpp",
        "im/src/halideimage.cpp",
        "im/src/hybrid.cpp",
        "im/src/hybridimage.cpp",
        "im/src/options.cpp",
        preview_source,
        "im/src/pybuffer.cpp",
        "im/src/pycapsule.cpp",
        "im/src/structcode.cpp",
        "im/src/typecode.cpp",
        "im/src/module.cpp"
    ],
}
```

… adding this new bit chooses the right file for compilation – but it fails to compile at all on Mac OS X. Apparently `distutils`/`setuptools` doesn’t recognize the “.mm” extension as a source file:

[image: unknown file type '.mm']

> error: unknown file type '.mm'

I am no expert when it comes to `distutils` and `setuptools` platform-specific configuration – what’s a simple way to conditionally add this one source file to the source file list on the Mac?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, did you ever find some solution?

It looks like '.mm' is not supported in my version of distutils but '.m' is. So I separated the C++ parts of the .mm file into a .cpp file, and create a small C header to access the .m file from that .cpp.

Comment: The thing I ended up doing was all the renaming `.mm` files to `.m` files and then adding `-x objective-c++` to the compiler args – a solution which is neither portable (I think `-x` is a clang-only thing) nor amenable (considering the files are essentially now mis-named). Your solution sounds cleaner but equally unagreeable for the long-term… I am still seeking a real solution to the problem, indeed.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. What is the problem of using .m files, it seems to work just fine. It seems a long outstanding bug that distutils doesn't handle .mm. I found some bug report + patch from 2001 (16 years ago!!!) about this: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2001-December/002695.html

Comment: One problem with having to use `.m` is that, in cases where the implementation is joined-at-the-hip Objective-C++ – and as such can’t be readily broken out into translation units by language, as you were able to do – you end up with a bastard-of-Winterfell sort of file that does not play nice with e.g. Xcode or cmake, etc. In reality it is not, as you point out, the end of the world – it is the kind of problem that does inflame my programmers’ OCD, though; while the file suffix is only one datum, it remains the most reliable metadatum you have for a file, and so. But still: 16-year bug, what?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a project where I ran into this problem. Here is something that I put together. Its kind of hacky but it works.

```py
from distutils.unixccompiler import UnixCCompiler
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext

class DarwinInteropBuildExt(build_ext):
    def initialize_options(self):

        # add support for ".mm" files
        UnixCCompiler.src_extensions.append(".mm")
        UnixCCompiler.language_map[".mm"] = "objc"

        # then intercept and patch the compile and link methods to add needed flags
        unpatched_compile = UnixCCompiler._compile
        unpatched_link = UnixCCompiler.link

        def patched_compile(self, obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts):
            # define language specific compile flags here
            if ext == ".cpp":
                patched_postargs = extra_postargs + ["-std=c++17"]
            elif ext == ".mm":
                patched_postargs = extra_postargs + [
                    "-ObjC++",
                    "-fobjc-weak",
                    "-fobjc-arc",
                ]
            else:
                patched_postargs = extra_postargs
            unpatched_compile(self, obj, src, ext, cc_args, patched_postargs, pp_opts)

        def patched_link(
                self,
                target_desc,
                objects,
                output_filename,
                output_dir=None,
                libraries=None,
                library_dirs=None,
                runtime_library_dirs=None,
                export_symbols=None,
                debug=0,
                extra_preargs=None,
                extra_postargs=None,
                build_temp=None,
                target_lang=None,
        ):
            # define additional linking arguments here if needed
            existing_postargs = extra_postargs or []
            framework_postargs = [
                "-framework", "Cocoa",
                "-framework", "Metal",
                "-framework", "QuartzCore",
            ]
            unpatched_link(
                self,
                target_desc,
                objects,
                output_filename,
                output_dir,
                libraries,
                library_dirs,
                runtime_library_dirs,
                export_symbols,
                debug,
                extra_preargs,
                existing_postargs + framework_postargs,
                build_temp,
                target_lang,
            )
        UnixCCompiler._compile = patched_compile
        UnixCCompiler.link = patched_link
        super().initialize_options()

# ...


setup(
    # use the custom cmd class here
    cmdclass={"build_ext": DarwinInteropBuildExt},
)
```